# store system output to database table using rake task

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, rake

i'm writing a rake task to execute a python script and storing the result in a variable. I want to parse the output and search for certain keys and store its values to a database table. If i store the result in a variable it will be in a string format so i can't search using keys. I can direct the output to a file and parse the file to get the values but in either case storing the output as an hash would be the better solution.

```
namespace :extract do
  desc 'extract colors from image url'
  task :color => :environment do
    extract_color
  end
  def extract_color
    Images.all.each do |a|
    url = a.image_link
    result = `cd ~/color_picker/ && python color_extrat.py #{url}`
    puts result
    end
  end
end
```

Here the output format http://pastebin.com/y26SEZEe

I want to achieve something similar to this

```
    Color.create!(
      family: result["family"], 
      count: result["count"],
      name: result["name"],
      vvalue: result["v"],
      rgb: result["rgb"],
      etc..         
   )
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. What are you asking?

Comment: i mentioned what i want to achieve. I want to parse the output and save certain values like family, count, rgb value etc to the database table

Comment: Are you asking for help with the parsing? With how to store the parsed data? Something else?